# Azure CosmosDb with mongo error - "MongoError: query in command must target a single shard key"

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a cosmosdb database with Sharedkey. When my service run, it remove all documents by sharedkey field and insert the next. But during tests I had duplicateds inserts without  errors notifys.I't have permission to directly delete the collection. This's customer envirronment and has process to change database.
I'd like to remove all collection documents. But has duplicated SharedKey fields and throw this error message:

```
MongoError: query in command must target a single shard key
```

When list by shared key
[image]

When try to remove by shared key
[image]

Hey friends somebody can "give me a hand"?

Obrigado!!!

Comment: Can [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c07b3390-0be6-4da5-a32f-c262f577394c/azure-cosmosdb-mongomongoose-deletemany-fails-if-partioned?forum=azurecosmosdb) help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. To fix i had to remove all data and move to another collection with once sharedkey.

The best solutions was to change to Atlas MongoDb

Answer (score 1):

Just like what some engineer said in the website I mentioned in the comment,

> We have got the same feedback from PG team that you got on the support
> ticket that you **drop the entire collection using drop() instead of
> deletemany()**. So please follow the same for getting this issue
> resolved.

So the solution to your error is use drop() instead.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all collection documents, you can use the 'drop()' command. For more information on this, you can go through the [MongoDB Documentation on drop()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/index.html)